# fitting a non-linear term in a logistic regression

Tags: r, logistic, splines, nonlinearity

I am running a logistic regression and I have run a box Tidwell test which seems to suggest that two of the IVs that I have in my model are non-linear. I have attempted to fit restricted cubic splines to the terms using Frank Harrell's HMISC/RMS packages. However, for one of the terms I get the following error message:

```
In rcspline.eval(x, nk = nknots, inclx = TRUE, pc = pc, fractied = fractied) :
  could not obtain 5 interior knots with default algorithm.
```

On reading some other questions on this site, it seems that the use of restricted cubic splines is inappropriate for this variable. If this is the case, are there alternatives that allow me to account for the non-linearity?

I should mention that the predictor in question is a count variable (number of arrests) extremely positively skewed and discrete.

I have tried transforming the variable using cube root transform, but this has had no effect and I still attain the same error message.

The variable in question has the following count distribution

```
  X    1     2     3     4     5     6     7      8     9    10    11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18    19    20    23    24    25    26    28    30  46  72
    53738  8059  2547   999   411   198   100    64    47    30    15    11     6     6     4     9     3     1     3     6     1     1     1     1     4     1  1  1
```

Comment: "I should mention that the predictor in question is extremely positively skewed and discrete." Please provide more details. Is this an ordinal variable? If yes, how many levels are there?

Comment: I have clarified. It is a count variable, so I have not put in the number of levels.

Comment: OK, but how many different counts are there? From the error message I'd infer that you don't have enough values for the degrees of freedom of the spline.

Comment: AH, I see thanks for the clarification. I have included the frequency for each level. There are 28 levels.

Comment: I think that if you do not tell it where to put the knots it uses quantiles and with such a concentration of 1's you may be having a problem there. You could try specifying explicitly where to put the knots. Alternatively try transforming your original variable and stop using splines.